# revtex4-2 compile error issue: missing \begin{document}

Tags: revtex

A really odd bug that breaks compilation has developed and I am stuck fixing it.

files that compile fine on my desktop throw an error on laptop. Here is an mwe. First, using revtex4, it compiles without error:

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Myname}

\begin{abstract}

This is my abstract

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

This is my document

\end{document}
```

but if I switch to revtex4-2:

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Myname}

\begin{abstract}

This is my abstract

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

This is my document

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \begin{document}
```

Latex definitely knows about the style files (the log file starts with statements to that effect). I have reinstalled Mactex. No change. I have also tried compiling the revtex4-2 examples in the style file directory.

Grateful for any insight here...

Comment: The fact that it works on one machine but not on another is usually a hint to some non up-to-date distribution. Please add `\listfiles` somewhere in the preamble and post the output here.

Comment: check also the latex format (at the begin of the log-file). If you have a new latex (2020-10-01) you also need a new revtex4-2 (revtex4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e).

Comment: Ok so the aps website is out of date, only refers to 4.2c

Comment: Is there a canonical way to keep revtex up to date? The unzip in some directory method seems brittle

Comment: @AshtonBradley The APS website contains RevTeX 4.2e: https://journals.aps.org/revtex, but you can also get it from CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex.  However MacTeX (based on TeX Live) should ship with the latest version...

Comment: `*File List*
revtex4-2.cls    2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
  aps4-2.rtx
aps10pt4-2.rtx
textcase.sty    2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
revsymb4-2.sty    2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-05-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)`

but mactex claims to be up to date. Multiple versions maybe?

Comment: look more as if you have a local version interfering (your l3backend is quite current). Check the pathes in the logs.

Comment: ok, so manually updating under `Library/texmf` fixed it. Thanks all, sorry for the basic questions here. A bit of extra confusion as google was serving up old aps pages as first hits